# jsessionid appearing in resource URLs when accessing app via loadbalanced URL

Tags: jsf, openshift, jsessionid, jboss-eap-7

I'm porting an old application from WebLogic to JBoss EAP 7.4. The application fully works in my local EAP 7.4 environment and it uses JSF (so xhtml files).

When we deployed the application to the test environment on Openshift, the application kept working fine if we accessed it from the hostname of the Openshift pod where it's hosted.

But the application breaks when the DNS for the test environment was switched from the old WebLogic one to the new Openshift one. In particular, it generates links with jsessionId appended to them, for example in the icon to change language:

```
<form id="change_Language_Form" name="change_Language_Form" method="post" action="/context/myappname/pages/MyPage.xhtml;jsessionid=BacTT73WcuQB9E6fi9TIU1SL7aOt58SP3J5i1QbM.myapp-40-j5w9n" class="wrap" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
```

or in an iframe that includes a CSS:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/static-context/Css/template.css;jsessionid=A1-3JO4DzGpUohA2Hz34mC5C8RE9zjLIQfRaG_QP.myapp-40-j5w9n">
```

(I just noticed that the two sessionIds from the same page at the same time are different, is this a problem?)

The static resources are served by an Apache front end from the /static-context path, whereas the application is deployed in the /context path.

I tried to look for solutions to this:

- MKyong suggests turning page session off in the JSP, but we don't have JSPs, we have xhtml pages with facelets.
- Other stackoverflow responses suggest setting `<tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>` in the web.xml which completely breaks the application.

In the old weblogic.xml file there was this setting:

```
<session-descriptor>
<cookie-name>MYSESSIONID</cookie-name>
<session-descriptor>
```

Obviously JBoss doesn't read this file. Could this be the issue? What's the equivalent for JBoss?

Comment: This behavior is due to the cookie validation mechanism. If cookies are disabled by the user, the session ID is placed in the URL. From here you should think about a solution that meets your needs.

Comment: I'm testing it on Chrome, and I don't have disabled cookies (I only have uBlock Origin but I don't think that's the issue). The application works perfectly on my local EAP 7.4 installation and even on Openshift but only if I reach it through the hostname of the Openshift pod, not through the DNS. What could make JSF think that cookies are disabled by the user?

Comment: there is virtually no way for the server to check if cookies are disabled. therefore (usually) a check is made for the presence of a specific cookie. the reason you have different behavior is the change of the domain you use (the cookies that the browser sends). review what cookies are saved in the browser for the different domains and why the missing ones are not set for the new domain

Comment: The WebLogic setting that you mention just changes the session cookie name to MYSESSIONID.
I'm not sure if that's really going to help you, but at JBoss EAP 7 you can do the same as follows:

**# standalone**
`/subsystem=undertow/servlet-container=default/setting=session-cookie:add(name=MYSESSIONID)`

**# domain**
`/profile=profilename/subsystem=undertow/servlet-container=default/setting=session-cookie:add(name=MYSESSIONID)`